# Unity Registry with Observer Pattern, how?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a concrete class that takes a collection of observers implementing an observer pattern.
I'm construction injecting the list of observers.

How to I register the Implementations and Concretes using Unity?

ex:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private IObserver[] _observers;
    public MyService(params IObserver[] observers){
             _observers = observers;
    }

    public void MyMethod(MyObject myObject){

        foreach(var ob in _observers){
               ob.Execute(myObject);
        }
    }
}

public class Ob1 : IObserver{
      public void Execute(MyObject obj){
           //do something
       }
}

public class Ob2 : IObserver{
      public void Execute(MyObject obj){
           //do something
       }
}

public class MyRegistry : UnityRegistry
{
    public MyRegistry(){
        ///What Goes Here??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private IObserverManager observerManager;

    public MyService(IObserverManager obsManager){
             this.observerManager = obsManager;
    }

    public void MyMethod(MyObject myObject){

        IObserver[] observers = this.observerManager.GetObservers();
        foreach(var ob in observers){
               ob.Execute(myObject);
        }
    }
}

public class ObserverManager : IObserverManager {
    public List<IObserver> GetObservers(){
        ... some code to return the list of observers
    }

    public void RegisterObserver(IObserver obs)
    {
        ... add obs to list of obs
    }
}

public class Ob1 : IObserver{
      public void Execute(MyObject obj){
           //do something
       }
}

public class Ob2 : IObserver{
      public void Execute(MyObject obj){
           //do something
       }
}

public class StrategyResolver : IStrategyResolver
{
    private IUnityContainer container;

    public StrategyResolver(IUnityContainer c)
    {
         this.container = c;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>(String namedStrategy){
         return this.container.Resolve<T>(namedStrategy); 
    }
}

public class MyRegistry : UnityRegistry
{
    private IUnityContainer container;

    public MyRegistry(IUnityContainer c)
    {
       this.container = c;
    }

    public MyRegistry(){
        this.container.RegisterType<IObserverManager, ObserverManager>();
        this.container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService();
        this.container.RegisterType<ISomeClass, SomeClass>();
        this.container.RegisterType<IObserver, ObserverA>("CategoryA");
        this.container.RegisterType<IObserver, ObserverB>("CategoryB");
        this.container.RegisterType<IStrategyResolver, StrategyResolver>();
    }
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
     private IObserverManager observerManager;
     private IStrategyResolver strategyResolver;

     public SomeClass(IObserverManager oManager, IStrategyResolver sResolver)
     {
         this.observerManager = oManager;
         this.strategyResolver = sResolver;
     }

     public void Process(MyObject obj)
     {
         IObserver obs = this.strategyResolver.Resolve<IObserver>(obj.Category);
         this.observerManager.RegisterObserver(obs);

         ...etc....
     }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work since the strategy relies on on the IoC (Unity)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give names for the registrations of `IObserver` and unity would be able to resolve the array of observers correctly:

```
public class MyRegistry : UnityRegistry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        Register<IMyService, MyService>();
        Register<IObserver, Ob1>().WithName("observer1");
        Register<IObserver, Ob2>().WithName("observer2");
    }
}
```